# tar produces different tarball from one directory on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, backup, md5, tar

I'm using tar to backup my hg repositories on a Mac Server. I always keep a copy of the last created tarball, compare the md5 sum of the new one and the last one and if it is different I upload the new tarball into a private bucket on amazon s3.

So far so good, this is an reliable approach, working perfectly on Linux or FreeBSD.

However, on Mac OS X I found that every single tarball has been uploaded to amazon s3 and finally I found that two tarballs created one directly after the other on a otherwise completely untouched directory have a different check and sometimes even a slightly different size.

However, when unpacking two tarballs with different md5 sum and comparing the output, the output is equal! Or, at least, diff does not found a difference. And, of course, it is equal to the originally packed source directory.

I read a lot about excluding .DS_Store and ._* files. But it doesn't change things.

Any hint for me?

Thanks,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that stored access time or modification time for some files has changed between creating the tar archive. If you gzip the tar files that could also explain the size difference.

Comment: Do you know whether I can disable the access time on the Mac? Something like noatime in the good old /etc/fstab ...

Comment: Can't find anything in the man pages for tar for doing so. Maybe some other more advanced tar archiver like [star](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/star) can do it.

Comment: Otherwise try to figure out which file(s) that has changed creation or modification time.